# a problem in Stein's book 'Real analysis', relate to continuum hypothesis.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, real-numbers, axioms

The question is from [chapter 2, problem 5](https://books.google.com/books?id=2Sg3Vug65AsC&pg=PA97) in Stein's book 'Real analysis':

> 5. There is an ordering $≺$ of $\mathbb R$ with the property that for each $y\in\mathbb R$ the set $\{x\in\mathbb R : x ≺ y\}$ is at most countable.
>      The existence of this ordering depends on the continuum hypothesis, which
>      asserts: whenever $S$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb R$, then either $S$ is countable, or $S$ has
>      the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ (that is, can be mapped bijectively to $\mathbb R$.)
>
>    [Hint: Let $≺$ denote a well-ordering of $\mathbb R$, and define the set $X$ by $X = \{y \in
>    \mathbb R \mid \{x \mid x ≺ y\} \text{ is not countable}\}$. If $X$ is empty we are done. Otherwise,
>      consider the smallest element $y \in X$, and use the continuum hypothesis.]

I cannot figure out how this hint will work?

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $y$ be the smallest element in $X$. Then $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\prec y\}$ is uncountable, so by the continuum hypothesis it must have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$. Therefore there is a certain very nice kind of function between $\{x\in\Bbb R:x\prec y\}$ and $\Bbb R$ that you can use to define an ordering of $\Bbb R$ with the desired property.

Comment: Doesn't the claim follow easily from AC+CH to get $\Bbb R\approx\omega_1$, so that a bijection from $\omega_1$ would have countable initial segments?

Comment: @Mario: Yes, but I’d just about bet that the ordinals aren’t available here. This is pretty clearly a way to get the result without needing more than the most basic notions of cardinality.

Comment: Why is $X$ in bijection with $\Bbb R$? I understand why $\{x\in\Bbb R:x<y\}$ is in bijection with $\Bbb R$, because it is uncountable, but I don't understand for $X$.

Comment: @Alphonse: That was a bad typo: it was supposed to be $\{x\in\Bbb R:x<y\}$.

Comment: Why does such a smallest element $y$ exist in $X$? Should I be able to rule out the possibility that $X$ is infinite?

Comment: @AlanJenkins: No, $X$ could be infinite; but $\prec$ **well-orders** $\Bbb R$, so if $X\ne\varnothing$, then $X$ has a $\prec$-minimal element $y$. (Note that I’ve just edited the answer. As originally written it had $<$ where it really ought to have had $\prec$, the well-order in the statement of the question.)